# how to find element in MongoDB by Id ? ( scala/lift)

Tags: mongodb, lift

I'm trying to find a value from MongoDB by id using:

```
var id = S.param("id") openOr ""
val qry = QueryBuilder.start("id").is(id).get
def render = {
    val items = Delegacja.findAll(qry)   

    ".my_list *" #> items.map(e => 
      ".my_list_item" #> <li>{e.gdzie_od1}</li> &
      ".my_list_item_id" #> <li>{e.id}</li>
    )
}
```

Model:

```
package code.model
import _root_.net.liftweb.record.field._
import net.liftweb.mongodb.record._
import net.liftweb.mongodb.record.field.ObjectIdPk

class Delegacja private() extends MongoRecord[Delegacja] with ObjectIdPk[Delegacja]{
  def meta = Delegacja

  object gdzie_od1 extends StringField(this, 30)
  object gdzie_do1 extends StringField(this, 30)
  object data_od1 extends StringField(this, 500)
  object data_do1 extends StringField(this, 500)
}

object Delegacja extends Delegacja with MongoMetaRecord[Delegacja]
```

or just `val items = Delegacja.find("Id" -> id)` or `val items = Delegacja.find("Id" -> id.toString)` or `val items = Delegacja.find("id", id)` and nothing found, ID is good, when I'm looking by some name its ok but by id no results..
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

---

Hmm I think have some clue. ( And really in `find` change `id` to `_id` ;) )

When I'm doing :

```
val md1 = Delegacja.createRecord.gdzie_od1(gdzie_od1).gdzie_do1(gdzie_do1).save
S.notice(md1.id.is.toString)
val md = Delegacja.find("_id", md1.id.is.toString)
S.notice(md.is.toString)
```

I get `Empty` from `S.notice(md.is.toString)` but when I change `val md = Delegacja.find("_id", md1.id.is.toString)` to `val md = Delegacja.find("_id", md1.id.is)` is ok so in `viewitem.scala` I need to somehow convert `string ( id )` which I get as param from link to `oibjectid`, how to deal with it?

```
class ViewItem {

  var id = S.param("id") openOr ""
          val qry = QueryBuilder.start("_id").is(id).get
  def render = {

    val items = Delegacja.find("_id", id) // THIS id.ToObjectIdPK some how ..
     S.notice(items.toString)

    ".my_list *" #> items.map(e => 
      ".my_list_item" #> <li>{e.gdzie_od1}</li> &
      ".my_list_item_id" #> <li>{e.id}</li>
    )
  }
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah mean while I get answer:

need new import:

```
import org.bson.types.ObjectId
```

And :

```
 val items = Delegacja.find("_id", new ObjectId(id))
```

This is the needed conersion ;]